# SOAP WebServices :how can i implement spring mvc application using SOAP?

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc, soap

I want to develop a mvc application where I want to perform a CRUD operation and  show in jsp page. The flow will be `jsp -> spring mvc (SOAP) -> hibernate -> database`, I have developed a similar flow `jsp -> spring mvc (REST) -> hibernate -> database` but in that case I was returning JSON and was consuming it through javascript.

But in case of SOAP how should I fit it in my application and how should I return data to my view ? Can anyone provide me an example how to get request to controller using SOAP and process the data using hibernate and return the data back to jsp?

Comment: What research have you done on using SOAP?

Comment: MVC != SOAP. You want spring-ws.

Comment: @Bob Dalgleish as i am new to SOAP services i have gone through some of the tutorials for SOAP,that are basically focused on creating a web service and WSDL generation but i said earlier i worked on the REST part of my problem using REST i was able to generate JSON data and use it in my view part but in case of SOAP as it is XML oriented i am not able to link  how i will use the XML for my view part